# getAllContentServices returns Huge Data

Tags: yodlee

I am using Yodlee “getAllContentServices” API to get all content services. But service returns a
     huge amount of data (More Than 26 MBs) and returns more than 12k records, which is very difficult 
     to handle in a single service call, Is it any other way exist to access this service page wise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to do this -

1. call [getAllContentServices](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllContentServices) and pass "notrim=false" and then for each contentService ID you can call - [getContentServiceInfo1](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getContentServiceInfo1) with desired reqSpecifier to get the information.

OR

2. Use [getContentServicesByContainerType2](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getContentServicesByContainerType2) and get the list of content services based on the container type.

Comment: Thanks for Quick reply.
I have already tried both the approaches and worked as expected.
But i need to get All Content service iterate them and store into my DB.
Approach 1 worked properly, But Required more than 12K HTTP calls to get all information.

Comment: Currently those two are the only option but I will recommend using the 2nd one. I will also take this as a feedback and forward it to Yodlee's internal team.

Comment: Thanks again.
2nd Approach will save lots of HTTP calls.