# Yodlee getAllContentServices not responding

Tags: yodlee

This is a technical question about Yodlee '/jsonsdk/ContentServiceTraversal/getAllContentServices' API. 
I have followed a tutorial on how to call on Yodlee and have the following code:

```
  query({
    :endpoint => '/jsonsdk/ContentServiceTraversal/getAllContentServices',
    :method => :POST,
    :params => {
      :cobSessionToken=> cobrand_token,
      :notrim=> true
    }
  })
```

where def query is the following:

```
def query opts
  method = opts[:method].to_s.downcase
  response = self.class.send(method, opts[:endpoint], query: opts[:params])
  data=response.parsed_response
  log_query(opts.merge({response:data, code:response.code}))  

  if response.success?
    if[TrueClass, FalseClass, Fixnum].include?(data.class)
      data
    else
      convert_to_mash(data)
    end
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

My question is when I set the "notrim: true" in query, my query response does not return anything. However, when I set "notrim: false" in query, the call to API would run normally. Can someone give me an explanation and solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass notrim: true , the data returned is huge and close to 25 mb and hence it takes time and may lead to connection time out and hence you may not be getting the response from the API.

Please go through the below post to understand how to use an alternate method.

[getallcontentservices-returns-huge-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271043/getallcontentservices-returns-huge-data)